# smarty get array element, if key ends with *

Tags: php, smarty

Is there a way in smarty to get array element, if key ends with "_description_name"?

E.g to do this in jquery it would be: [array$="_description_name"]

Example:

```
[index] => Array
    (
        [language_id] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [language_id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => language_id
                                [value] => 1
                                [fvalue] => 1
                            )

                        [extra_description_name] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => extra_description_name
                                [value] => Paint Colours
                            )
```

I want to get the text "Paint Colours", without the "extra_". So I want the same code to work if this was change to `product_description_name`.

I see this working in 2 parts:

```
1. {assign var="name" value=$index.language_id[1]|endsWith:'_description_name'}
2. {if $name.value}{$name.value}{/if}
```

But the `endWith` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to try `{...|preg_match:'/_description_name$/'}`